# How to debug a TSLint error?

Tags: node.js, angular, webstorm, tslint

I'm using webstorm, and an Angular 2 app.  Something has changed and it appears tslint doesn't like my tslint.json file.

```
 TSLint: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

I have no idea how to begin debugging it as the error isn't indicating (that i can see) where in the tslint file is the problem.

BTW, I've taken the default tslint file coming with the project, i haven't made any changes.

Is there a validation command i can run on my tslint file that will show me where errors are?

Node: 7.8
TSLint: 5.1

TSLINT BELOW:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs"],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
    "component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "no-access-missing-member": true,
    "templates-use-public": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run **ng lint** command on your terminal and it will exactly show you line in which line number of file it has this error . Also it depends on how you've set your package.json.

Comment: i get: "You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the lint command."  but "ng serve" works fine.

Comment: Well in that case seems like something is misconfigured in your package.json. Either lint command is missing  or the global and local angular versions don't match.

Answer (score 0):

In `node_modules/tslint/lib/linter.js` find `applyRule` definition and replace line:

```
error_1.showWarningOnce("Warning: " + error.message);
```

with:

```
error_1.showWarningOnce("Warning: " + error.message + " " + error.stack);
```

I submitted the [issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2704).